# Jasper make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to install Jasper on my rpi.  It is currently running Raspbian.  I am following instructions on the Jasper installation page, but when I try to install openfst and run sudo make install I get an error:

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src'
Making install in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/include'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include"
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/arc.h fst/determinize.h fst/intersect.h fst/queue.h fst/statesort.h fst/arcfilter.h fst/dfs-visit.h fst/invert.h fst/randequivalent.h fst/string-weight.h fst/difference.h fst/lexicographic-weight.h fst/randgen.h fst/symbol-table.h fst/arcsort.h fst/encode.h fst/lock.h fst/random-weight.h fst/synchronize.h fst/epsnormalize.h fst/log.h fst/rational.h fst/test-properties.h fst/cache.h fst/equal.h fst/arc-map.h fst/map.h fst/register.h fst/topsort.h fst/closure.h fst/equivalent.h fst/matcher.h fst/matcher-fst.h fst/relabel.h fst/union-find.h fst/compact-fst.h fst/expanded-fst.h fst/minimize.h fst/replace.h fst/union.h '/usr/local/include/fst'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/compat.h fst/factor-weight.h fst/state-map.h fst/mutable-fst.h fst/reverse.h fst/util.h fst/complement.h fst/flags.h fst/partition.h fst/reweight.h fst/vector-fst.h fst/compose-filter.h fst/float-weight.h fst/product-weight.h fst/rmepsilon.h fst/verify.h fst/compose.h fst/fst-decl.h fst/project.h fst/rmfinalepsilon.h fst/visit.h fst/concat.h fst/fst.h fst/properties.h fst/shortest-distance.h fst/weight.h fst/connect.h fst/fstlib.h fst/prune.h fst/shortest-path.h fst/const-fst.h fst/heap.h fst/push.h fst/state-table.h fst/slist.h fst/pair-weight.h fst/config.h fst/tuple-weight.h fst/power-weight.h fst/lookahead-matcher.h '/usr/local/include/fst'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst/script'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/script/arcsort.h fst/script/arg-packs.h fst/script/closure.h fst/script/compile-impl.h fst/script/compile.h fst/script/compose.h fst/script/concat.h fst/script/connect.h fst/script/convert.h fst/script/decode.h fst/script/determinize.h fst/script/difference.h fst/script/disambiguate.h fst/script/draw-impl.h fst/script/draw.h fst/script/encode.h fst/script/epsnormalize.h fst/script/equal.h fst/script/equivalent.h fst/script/fst-class.h fst/script/fstscript.h fst/script/info-impl.h fst/script/info.h fst/script/intersect.h fst/script/invert.h fst/script/map.h fst/script/minimize.h fst/script/print-impl.h fst/script/print.h fst/script/project.h fst/script/prune.h fst/script/push.h fst/script/randequivalent.h fst/script/randgen.h fst/script/register.h fst/script/relabel.h fst/script/replace.h fst/script/reverse.h fst/script/reweight.h fst/script/rmepsilon.h '/usr/local/include/fst/script'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/types.h fst/add-on.h fst/label-reachable.h fst/accumulator.h fst/interval-set.h fst/state-reachable.h fst/lookahead-filter.h fst/generic-register.h fst/edit-fst.h fst/replace-util.h fst/icu.h fst/string.h fst/signed-log-weight.h fst/sparse-tuple-weight.h fst/sparse-power-weight.h fst/expectation-weight.h fst/symbol-table-ops.h fst/bi-table.h fst/mapped-file.h '/usr/local/include/fst'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst/extensions/pdt'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/extensions/pdt/collection.h fst/extensions/pdt/compose.h fst/extensions/pdt/expand.h fst/extensions/pdt/info.h fst/extensions/pdt/paren.h fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h fst/extensions/pdt/pdtlib.h fst/extensions/pdt/pdtscript.h fst/extensions/pdt/replace.h fst/extensions/pdt/reverse.h fst/extensions/pdt/shortest-path.h '/usr/local/include/fst/extensions/pdt'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst/extensions/far'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/extensions/far/compile-strings.h fst/extensions/far/create.h fst/extensions/far/equal.h fst/extensions/far/extract.h fst/extensions/far/far.h fst/extensions/far/farlib.h fst/extensions/far/farscript.h fst/extensions/far/info.h fst/extensions/far/main.h fst/extensions/far/print-strings.h fst/extensions/far/stlist.h fst/extensions/far/sttable.h '/usr/local/include/fst/extensions/far'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/fst/script'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  fst/script/script-impl.h fst/script/shortest-distance.h fst/script/shortest-path.h fst/script/symbols.h fst/script/synchronize.h fst/script/text-io.h fst/script/topsort.h fst/script/union.h fst/script/weight-class.h fst/script/fstscript-decl.h fst/script/verify.h '/usr/local/include/fst/script'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/include'
Making install in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/lib'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/lib'
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libfst.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfst.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libfst.so.1.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libfst.so.1.0.0 libfst.so.1 || { rm -f libfst.so.1 && ln -s libfst.so.1.0.0 libfst.so.1; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libfst.so.1.0.0 libfst.so || { rm -f libfst.so && ln -s libfst.so.1.0.0 libfst.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfst.lai /usr/local/lib/libfst.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/lib'
Making install in script
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/script'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./../include    -g -O2 -MT push.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/push.Tpo -c -o push.lo push.cc
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./../include -g -O2 -MT push.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/push.Tpo -c push.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/push.o
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [push.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src/script'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/openfst-1.3.3/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem!  I changed my swap size to 500 and it worked!  I thought I had already changed it, but apparently you need to restart the rpi (of course) and I forgot to.